# Inserting globalresources into input type="submit"

Tags: asp.net

This is my code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Pay with Money Bookers"/>
```

I try to use global resources to display the value as I'm making a Multi language page. But when I try to do this:

```
<input type="submit" value='<%$ Resources:language, PaywithMoney%>'/>
```

I receive an error:

> Literal expressions like '<%$ Resources:language, PaywithMoney%>' are not allowed. Use asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:language, PaywithMoney%>" /> instead.

Anyone knows how do I rectify this? I try another method and called a function `GetGlobalRecsources` but when I display the button, the wording I receive is Submit a query. This problem also occur for `input type="hidden`.